# How can I make a countdown timer?

Tags: c#

I want to make a countdown timer in C#, WinForms. I want to be able to select a date from a DateTimePicker and make the timer count down to it showing remaining days, hours, minutes and seconds. How could I go about doing this?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: @UweKeim

More like a personal project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Instantiate a timer object
2. set the interval
3. assign a handler for the "tick" event
4. do your job:

   1. get the date
   2. calculate the remaining time

should do the trick.

Comment: +1 for not giving away fully functioning code to a question that shows little effort.

Comment: @walther

I know how to instantiate a timer. I can set the interval and assign a handler for the "tick" event but how do I calculate the remaining time. I have trouble understanding DateTime values and aren't sure how to subtract them.